# SiteGround with WordPress - CRON "Could not open input file" error

Tags: wordpress, cron

I have a WordPress site on SiteGround and have set up a CRON job using SiteGround's Cron Jobs tool.

I need to execute this file twice every hour:

```
/home/*********/public_html/*****/mycoolfile.php
```

There is nothing wrong in the file and it works just fine if executed manually, so it's nothing in the actual code.

The CRON command is:

```
php -q /home/*********/public_html/*****/mycoolfile.php
```

I've tried it with and without the -q flag.

Every 30 minutes I get an email from the CRON system stating:

> Could not open input file: `/home/*********/public_html/*****/mycoolfile.php`

File permissions are R/W/E for "Owner" which should be enough. Any ideas?

Comment: In your php file you can do `var_dump(__FILE__)` to see what the actual path is for this file. Maybe it is different from what you expect. If that doesn’t help, you can use curl instead of php for you cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a flaw in their AI help bot that was recently introduced as the primary tool for getting assistance with issues.

The server segment of the path the bot kept suggesting was sometimes incorrect and other times correct but saying to swap out parts that weren’t meant to swap out.

The correct path was:
php /home/customer/www/*********/public_html/*****/mycoolfile.php